# Restrict android map based application to specific city

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api

i am developing a map based application.Currently i am planning to implement my app within a city only.So i want to provide notifications(example : Service not available in your location) for those users who uses my application beyond  that city.I searched a lot through internet and through my friends.Someone advised me that each city have longitude,latitude range and filter users with that range .I don't know whether is a good logic or not.Currently i am standing in zero,may be its so simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your app only for small set of cities, of course, using the concrete location of cities and filter locations by radius will be the best.

If you want your app to be used only in cities (for any city) - you may try to get an address of location using this sample http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html
Part of code from where:

```
Address address = addresses.get(0);
String addressText = String.format(
       "%s, %s, %s",
       // If there's a street address, add it
       address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? ddress.getAddressLine(0) : "",
       // Locality is usually a city
       address.getLocality(),
       // The country of the address
       address.getCountryName());
return addressText;
```

You may analize the address variable and it's method getLocality():

```
/**
 * Returns the locality of the address, for example "Mountain View", or null if it is unknown.
 */
public String getLocality() {
    return mLocality;
}
```

If this method returns null, probably user is out of some known city or something else.

Comment: thanks for your advice but is there any way that we can check this from the server we use,i mean the apis??then we can reduce the client side calculations

Comment: I thought, that we always should reduce server side calcutations, but OK. These calculations is rather easy, so again it's no need to use your server. 
But if you want it so much, just send the location to server and use some algorithm where (here I can't help you) and retreive the result.
But again my advice is not to do this)
P.S. you may also store you previous calculations in client or server